# i cant change the column named oturum in mysql database with this code. Where is the mistake?

Tags: php, mysql

ı cant change the column named oturum with this code however. the id is true but not changing the database.

```
<?php 
include 'islemmerkezi/baglan.php';

ob_start();
session_start();
$id=$_GET['durum'];
echo "your id"; echo "<br>";
echo $id ; echo "<br>";
    $kullaniciguncelle=$db->prepare("UPDATE kullanici SET   
        oturum=:oturum
        WHERE id=@id
        ");
    $update=$kullaniciguncelle->execute(array(
        'oturum' => 0
    ));
session_destroy();
/*header("Location:login.php?durum=exit");*/
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Try changing `@id` to `$id`. Or much better if you use `:id` and include it in the array inside `execute()`

Comment: i tried  $id but did not work

Comment: Any error that appeared?

Comment: If you check the responses to your MySQL calls for errors it will tell you what is going wrong. Why do so few people do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the id as well. It is a variable data so you should use placeholder in SQL and then pass data in `execute()`:

```
$kullaniciguncelle = $db->prepare("UPDATE kullanici SET oturum=:oturum WHERE id=:id");
$kullaniciguncelle->execute([
    'oturum' => 0,
    'id' => $_GET['durum']
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE id=@id

after changing this to :

> WHERE id={$_POST['id]}

that it worked. Thx you al